# AWS User Pool with Angular App for authentication

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, authentication, jwt

I'm trying to wrap my head around the workflow for an Angular App using AWS Cognito user pools. I'm not interested in a full serverless app, but, would like to offload the authentication to Cognito. Wondering if I send a token back to Angular and store in local storage, would I check that each time I request an API from a server? In this case, I'm interested in creating my own Express server as I'm comfortable with that, alongside a mongodb database. Can someone explain the basic workflow for this hookup

Answer (score 0):

For one of my side projects I had an express server that handled my authentication/registration functions. This server would have middlewares which call cognito using the [cognito javascript sdk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html).

Login functions return jwt tokens which can be used passed into future requests. You can store these however you see fit (to keep it simple I stored my tokens in a httpOnly cookie). I then used [cognito-express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cognito-express) to validate requests made to other services.